# git hook to refuse adding files with certain extension

Tags: git, githooks

How to refuse pushing of *.bak files for example?

So new files with this extension and renaming to *.bak is blocked by the git server.

Answer (score 3):

Got some `pre-receive` hook working:

```
# refuse certain file name extensions
if [ "$newrev" != "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ] && [ "$oldrev" != "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]; then
    if forbidden="$(git show --pretty="format:" --name-only --diff-filter=A "$oldrev..$newrev" | egrep '\.(bak|old)$')"; then
        echo "============================";
        echo "";
        echo "FATAL ERROR: Forbiden file types detected:";
        echo "";
        printf '%s\n' "$forbidden"
        echo "";
        echo "============================";
        exit 1;
    fi
fi
```

It doesn't check the new branches for these files.

Answer (score 2):

you can write a simple git pre-commit hook script here:

```
git diff --cached --name-status | while read status file; do    
    # do a check only on the .bak files
    if [[ "$file" =~ ".bak$" ]] ; then
        echo "Please remove *.bak files before committing"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: I get this `zsh: read-only variable: status`. So I left it out `git diff --cached --name-only | while read file; do`

Answer (score 0):

what are the values for newrev and oldrev ?
git hook should work for all branches in the repository unless you specify particular branch name.
something like : git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref

Comment: That is a `pre-receive` server hook, it receives oldrev newrev and ref as parameters.

Comment: Instead of using server side hook, can you please try client side "pre-commit" hook as I posted in the earlier comment. It will suffice your requirement.

Comment: the pre-commit hooks add some deployment problems, no?

Comment: as per my knowledge it  doesn't. also the script is pretested , give it a try